# Java Bytecode edit

Tags: java, patch-reversing

[image]
Hi, I would like to edit one compiled java class file & like to insert & edit a couple of lines. I'm trying to make a patch for a software & when I compare this two file the only change I have seen in line 12 & 26.

As I'm not a java coder so I don't know how to do that but I read some articles & it suggests that to change a compiled java class there is only two way either get the source code or edit with bytecode editor. I tried to decompile the jar file but it shows huge error. So java byte editor is the only option.

I want to know how to change these parameters without decompiling the class file in java byte editor.

Please help me.

Comment: What do you want to change it too?